# How can I simplify a switch statement that executes a templated function?

Tags: c++, templates, enums, switch-statement

Consider the following [program](https://godbolt.org/z/TTPajh):

```
#include <string_view>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class A;
class B;
class C;

template<typename T>
void func1();
template<>
void func1<A>() {
    std::cout << "func 1 A";
}
template<>
void func1<B>(){
    std::cout << "func 1 B";
}
template<>
void func1<C>() {
    std::cout << "func 1 C";
}


template<typename T>
void func2();
template<>
void func2<A>() {
    std::cout << "func 2 A";
}
template<>
void func2<B>(){
    std::cout << "func 2 B";
}
template<>
void func2<C>() {
    std::cout << "func 2 C";
}

enum class my_enum { A, B, C};

void wrapper() {
    my_enum me = my_enum::A;
    switch (me) {
        case my_enum::A: func1<A>(); break;
        case my_enum::B: func1<B>(); break;
        case my_enum::C: func1<C>(); 
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    switch (me) {
        case my_enum::A: return func2<A>(); break;
        case my_enum::B: return func2<B>(); break;
        case my_enum::C: return func2<C>();
    }
}

int main() { wrapper(); }
```

Here `A`, `B` and `C` are classes and `func` is some templated function that is explicitly specialized.

As you can see, the following pattern:

```
switch(some_enum) {
   case SomeEnum::A: return func<A>();
   case SomeEnum::B: return func<B>();
   case SomeEnum::C: return func<C>();

   default:
      // error handling
}
```

needs to be repeated several times, but just with different functions. How can I simplify it?

The only thing I can think about is to define a macro, which is not very pretty.

Comment: *"templated function"* - That's a misnomer. There are no templated functions in C++. Simply because templates aren't classes *or* functions. They are instructions for generating them. What C++ does have is function templates. From which *different* functions get generated. Which is why the lookup table you have is pretty much as good as it gets.

Comment: Thank you for simplifying the example, but you might have abstracted away the purpose of the code. Is there an actual A/B/C object involved? Is the type identifier attached to an object like in a tagged union? A little extra context might yield a better solution

Comment: You don't. You leave these optimizations to the compiler

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch There's no question of optimizations anywhere. OP is asking for source code simplification.

Answer (score 2):

#### A Basic Solution For my_enum

A template template is normally the way to go for this kind of thing. Unfortunately, those only exist for types, and not for non-type parameters like function pointers.

But, turn those functions into functors:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct func1;

template<>
struct func1<A> {
    void operator ()() {
        std::cout << "func 1 A";
    }
};

/* etc */
```

And you're good to go:

```cpp
template <template <typename T> class F, typename... Args>
void dispatch(my_enum me, Args&&... args) {
    switch (me) {
        case my_enum::A: F<A>{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...); break;
        case my_enum::B: F<B>{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...); break;
        case my_enum::C: F<C>{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
}
```

usage:

```cpp
my_enum me = my_enum::A;
dispatch<func1>(me);
std::cout << '\n';
dispatch<func2>(me);
```

demo: https://godbolt.org/z/c6jPxa

#### Generalizing A Bit Further

If you're willing to get "clever", you can generalize `dispatch` too. Define some helper stubs:

```cpp
template <typename TEnum, TEnum... Es>
struct Tags {};

template <typename... Ts>
struct Types {};

template <typename TTags, typename TTypes>
struct Dispatch;
```

`Tags` and `Types` hold the enums, and types you want to test:

```cpp
template <template <typename T> class F>
using dispatch = typename Dispatch<
    Tags<my_enum, my_enum::A, my_enum::B, my_enum::C>, // the tags
    Types<A, B, C>                                     // their respective types
>::type<F>;
```

Then, you can generate that switch block by combining an initializer list, the comma operator, and the ternary operator.

```cpp
template <typename TEnum, TEnum... ETags, typename... TTypes>
struct Dispatch<Tags<TEnum, ETags...>, Types<TTypes...>> {
    template <template <typename T> class F>
    struct type {
        template <typename... Args>
        void operator()(TEnum e, Args&&... args)
        {
            (void)std::initializer_list<bool> {
                e == ETags ? (F<TTypes>{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...), false) : false...
            };
        }
    };
};
```

Usage:

```
template <template <typename T> class F>
auto dispatch = typename Dispatch<
    Tags<my_enum::A, my_enum::B, my_enum::C>,
    Types<A, B, C>
>::template type<F>{};

void wrapper() {
    my_enum me = my_enum::A;
    dispatch<func1>(me);
    std::cout << '\n';
    dispatch<func2>(me);
}
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Edhbrr

#### For Functions With Return Types

If you want your functors to return a value, it's a little trickier because you need a default return value if none of the tags match. This solution calls `F<void>{}(...)` in that case by recursively testing one argument and calling a dispatcher with the remaining arguments.

```cpp
template <typename TEnum, TEnum ETag, TEnum... ETags, typename TType, typename... TTypes>
struct Dispatch<Tags<TEnum, ETag, ETags...>, Types<TType, TTypes...>> {
    template <template <typename T> class F>
    struct type {
        template <typename... Args>
        auto operator()(TEnum e, Args&&... args) -> decltype(F<TType>{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
        {
            return e == ETag
                ? F<TType>{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
                : typename Dispatch<Tags<TEnum, ETags...>, Types<TTypes...>>::template type<F>{}(e, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    };
};

template <typename TEnum>
struct Dispatch<Tags<TEnum>, Types<>> {
    template <template <typename T> class F>
    struct type {
        template <typename... Args>
        auto operator()(TEnum e, Args&&... args) -> decltype(F<void>{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
        {
            return F<void>{}(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
    };
};
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/qz6r4T

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need a mapping from a closed set of types to enumeration elements:

```
enum SomeEnum;
SomeEnum constexpr id= ???;
return func<mapped_type<id>>();
```

that can be achieved throughout `std::tuple` API:

```
template<SomeEnum id>
using mapped_type=std::tuple_element_t<static_cast<std::size_t>(id), std::tuple<A,B,C>>;
```

but if the `id` is to be determined at run-time, `std::variant` API may provide a much better alternative.